# Like Confirm dialog on http://indafoto.hu

Tags: facebook, button, dialog, facebook-like, confirm

On our site: http://indafoto.hu the confirm dialog started popping up last day, what can we do about it?

Its a hungarian photo sharing community, please disable the confirm dialog, or help finding the cause of confirm.

I dont know anything of a clickjacking attempt, or anything harmful on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook auto spam detection system detected your website as a automatic liker

you need to wait if people like & confirm their likes your problem will solve automatically

PS : i dont have any problem with your website's like-box may this problem is for some users :)

Comment: Thanks, everything is fine now!